# Firebase first signIn with email and password in cordova : return auth/network error

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I use Firebase Auth system in a cordova app (so I followed javascript / web guidelines to implement Firebase api)

But my need is specific : 
users are added only in firebase admin interface (not from app) by an administrator, so they can after that login themselves in the app.

For the login, I use the firebase.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword function :

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(user=>{
        console.log('USER SERVICE : user exist', user.uid);
    })
    .catch((error)=> {
        console.log('USER SERVICE : user do not exist');
        console.log(error.code);
        console.log(error.message);
    }
);
```

I watch firebase auth using :

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=> {
    console.log(user)

    if (user) {
        console.log('USER SERVICE : user is signed in')
        this.user = user;
    } else {
        console.log('USER SERVICE : user is signed out')
    }       
});
```

But on first try (with valid email and password), it returns me the next error :

```
auth/network-request-failed
```

The watching function returns me a `null` user.

I have to try a second time with the same email/password, and it works.

Why this first fail, while user exist in firebase?

Thanks.

Comment: This seems very strange. What environment are you testing this in? does it occur in an emulator? Also can you check if an outgoing http request is occurring? It would be helpful if you can provide some logs to see what is going on.

Comment: @bojeil it seems the error happened only on Android device (Nexus 10) when running with cordova (on real device, not on emulator). On my ios device all seems good. I had a look at XHR request, in fact you're right, on first signIn, after app installation, there is no request. At second one, there are two request (verifyPassword, getAccountInfo). Strange... If I have a look on error code/message returned by first signin, i have : `auth/network-request-failed
A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.`

Comment: Can you check whether navigator.onLine is true or false for first request?

Comment: you're right @bojeil : on the first, even second request, sometimes, navigator.onLine is false...

Comment: Can you install cordova-plugin-network-information plugin? It corrects the unreliable behavior of navigator.onLine in a Cordova environmnet. Try that and let us know if the network errors stop occurring.

Comment: @bojeil I already installed this plugin, but i will try to use it for this case, with a condition.

Comment: I tried, and it is strange ! In the console, I have displayed both `navigator.onLine`, and `navigator.connection.type` (from network plug in). The first is false, but the second said that wifi is active  at the same time. The console display : `navigator.onLine is false;
navigator.connection.type cordova is wifi;
auth/network-request-failed;
A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.;`

Comment: Is there any limitation in number of connections in a minute with firebase ?

Comment: It seems I resolved the problem, to follow after longer tests. I made two changes : first, I had switched <form> to <div> in my html template for the login form, then I had added google urls to access tag in my config.xml : `<access origin="https://apis.google.com" />
  <access origin="https://www.googleapis.com" />
  <access origin=" https://securetoken.googleapis.com" />`. After 4 or 5 times,bug did not appears since i made this changes.